# Difference between command prompts in OS, in RoR, in Ruby, and in node.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, shell

When I type `command ..` in search bar, it displays

```
1. Command Prompt
2. Command prompt with Ruby
3. Command prompt with Ruby and Rails.
```

For running a ruby file, I usually use the command prompt with Ruby and Rails and run the command `ruby filename.rb`. However, if I use `$` sign in front of ruby like this `$ruby filename.rb`, then it raises an error. Tutorials say to use the command `$ruby filename` for executing a ruby file. Why does it show `$ruby is not recognised`?

1. What is the difference between command prompt, command prompt with Ruby, and command prompt with Ruby and Rails?
2. While I can run my ruby file with the command `ruby filename.rb`, why do the tutorials say to use `$` before ruby keyword for running a file?

Comment: I would suggest you to Do Google before posting such type of question there are plenty of answers present.

Answer (score 3):

By command prompts in Ruby or in Ruby on Rails, you probably mean a REPL such as irb or pry.

A command prompt (in OS) recognizes shell scripts, while irb or pry recognizes Ruby commands; they recognize different languages.

Different command prompts (or REPL) have different prompts, which helps in identifying which one you are using. When you see `$` in instructions, that is a prompt for shell scripts. You don't type the `$`; it is given, and you type commands after it. In irb or pry, the prompt is `>`; you don't type that character, but type commands after it.